# Cannot read an undeclared column 'smtp_port'

Tags: php, exception, nette

I am trying to get the Login page of my application but after putting username and password, error  is being displayed

> Cannot read an undeclared column 'smtp_port'

not able to figure out the reason behind this error.

**UserPresenter.php**

this is the code segment of presenter class

```
     $this->mailer = new Nette\Mail\SmtpMailer(array(
        'host' => $mailSetting->smtp_server,
        'port' => $mailSetting->smtp_port,
        'username' => $mailSetting->from_mail,
        'password' => $mailSetting->password,
        'secure' => $mailSetting->secure_connection,
    ));
```

**SmtpMailer.php**

```
 public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        if (isset($options['host'])) {
            $this->host = $options['host'];
            $this->port = isset($options['port']) ? (int) $options['port'] : NULL;
        } else {
            $this->host = ini_get('SMTP');
            $this->port = (int) ini_get('smtp_port');
        }
        $this->username = isset($options['username']) ? $options['username'] : '';
        $this->password = isset($options['password']) ? $options['password'] : '';
        $this->secure = isset($options['secure']) ? $options['secure'] : '';
        $this->timeout = isset($options['timeout']) ? (int) $options['timeout'] : 20;
        if (!$this->port) {
            $this->port = $this->secure === 'ssl' ? 465 : 25;
        }
        $this->persistent = !empty($options['persistent']);
    }
```

Comment: How is `$mailSetting` defined?

Comment: Sorry, cannot understand your question..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your ini configuration file did not have the key `smtp_port`, therefor it can't read or maybe some EOL misplace.

For testing purposes, you can directly put the port and run the code first and if it works it can make sure that issue is with `smtp_port` ini key.